# fieldset does not follow its parent's height

Tags: css, layout, html

I have been trying to solve this problem for a while, could not find solutions.

Here is my code

**CSS**

```
.parent{
    width:100px;
    display:table;
    border:1px solid green;
}

.child{
    width:50px;
    background:blue;
    display:table-cell;
    height: inherit;
}

.child + .child{
    background:red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">a <br/> b<br/> b<br/> b<br/> b<br/> b<br/> b</div>
        <div class="child" style="border: 2px dashed black">
            <fieldset style="height:100%;">a</fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want the `fieldset` in second child `div` to take the height of the parent `div`. So, the height of the `fieldset` should be equal to the `height` of child `div` it is in.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Height as a percentage works when the parent's height is declared.  In your case, `height: inherit;` but it's inheriting *nothing* from it's parent called `.parent`.  Setting `height` on `.parent` fixes it.  (Alternatively, you could set the `height` of the child called `.child` to something other than `inherit`.)

http://jsfiddle.net/HtAJw/

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">a <br/> b<br/> b<br/> b<br/> b<br/> b<br/> b</div>
    <div class="child" style="border: 2px dashed black">
        <fieldset style="height:100%;">a</fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{
    width:100px;
    display:table;
    border:1px solid green;
    height: 100%   /* <-- added height to parent */
}

.child{
    width:50px;
    background:blue;
    display:table-cell;
    height: inherit;
}

.child + .child{
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you much for the solution.. This worked for one of my problem. However i have ran into another problem.  1st child has other Div in it and when the page loads 2nd child with the fieldset start from the bottom of the parent div. I dont understand why its doing this? any solution

Comment: @lamaC, I don't quite understand your follow-up question.  It might be best to ask a new question and then include a jsFiddle demonstrating the new issue.  Generally, when you use height as a percentage, you have to be aware of the specified height of each parent up the chain.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Here is the link to my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121034/table-cell-in-div-is-not-working

Comment: @ Sparky672, This does not work with IE. Field set still does not take parents height in IE. check it http://jsfiddle.net/HtAJw/ in IE

Answer (score 1):

If you want the fieldset to always take up the entire area of its parent div, then make it

```
.child2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

(fix the values as appropriate).

Comment: To clarify, .child2 should be assigned to the fieldset.

Comment: And `position:relative;` should be added to .child or the fieldset will fill the whole page

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I had it set in my test page but missed here.

Comment: Thank you for the solution....However i still have a problem which is 1st child has other Div in it and when the page loads 2nd child with the fieldset start from the bottom of the parent div. I have tried changing the "top" value. However It does not do any good coz the other child heights varies when it shrinks it throws out the child2,